# Как сделать чтобы иконка становилось активной на jquery?

Tags: jquery, css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать чтобы иконка становилось активной

Comment: Иконка - это плюсик справа вверху?

Comment: Да нужно чтобы становилось активной, а при нажатии на другой плюсик был обычный

Comment: Я сделал все, больше не нужно

Comment: Если сделали, ответьте сами на свой вопрос, вставьте свой вариант реализации, не оставляйте вопрос открытым

Comment: Либо удалите вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.blocks').on('change', '.btn :checkbox', function() {
  let element = this;
  $('.btn :checkbox').each(function() {
    if (this != element) {
      this.checked = false;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.block {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 38px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  padding: 35px 30px 30px;
  position: relative;
  width: 560px;
}

.title {
  color: #242729;
  display: inline-block;
  font: 19px/1em Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.text {
  color: #242729;
  display: inline-block;
  font: 16px/1.6em Arial, sans-serif;
  padding-top: 18px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.btn>div {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/nN7gj.png) -516px -34px no-repeat;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 37px;
  left: 492px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
  width: 37px;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0.9) opacity(0.5);
  filter: grayscale(0.9) opacity(0.5);
}

.btn>input {
  display: none;
}

.btn>div:hover {
  transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0.1) opacity(0.9);
  filter: grayscale(0.1) opacity(0.9);
}

.btn>input:checked+div {
  transform: rotate(315deg);
  transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(128deg);
  filter: hue-rotate(128deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blocks">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="title">Кнопки которые активируют функции?</div>
    <label class="btn"><input type="checkbox"><div></div></label>
    <div class="text">Функции можно активировать кнопками мыши или клавиатуры, нажав их в нужном сочетании. Также, незастёгнутые кнопки на куртке могут деактивировать жизненные функции. А вот кнопка, положеная на стул, может активировать так, что функционировать будет
      часа два-три.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="title">Как реализовать это на jquery</div>
    <label class="btn"><input type="checkbox"><div></div></label>
    <div class="text">JQuery нужно использовать там, где это действительно необходимо. Но, раз надо, так надо...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="title">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <label class="btn"><input type="checkbox"><div></div></label>
    <div class="text">это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```